# Undefined reference for string constant in service

Tags: ros-fuerte, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when I define a simple service, e.g.

```
string my_string
string CONST_STRING=some_value
---
```

I get an undefined reference to ...::CONST_STRING during linking. Looking at the generated header file, I noticed that CONST_STRING gets declared, but never defined. I tested the same with messages, here it works fine and I can see the definition of CONST_STRING.

The same applies for floatXX-- I guess that problem exists for every constant that can not be encoded into an enum.

Am I doing something wrong,or is this a bug in gensrv? I'm working with Fuerte

Thanks a lot for your help!

Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49422/undefined-reference-for-string-constant-in-service/) by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, reported at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5587

---

Originally posted by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) with karma: 390 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-30**:
I think nowadays, after everything was moved to github, the ticket should be filed [here](https://github.com/ros/gencpp).

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2012-11-30**:
filed here now as well https://github.com/ros/gencpp/issues/2 . Hope it's in the right place now ;)

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2013-06-01**:
fixed, see https://github.com/ros/gencpp/issues/2#issuecomment-18780252. Thanks a lot, Dirk!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a bug to me, which you should report.

I can also confirm that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1